# Laravel 5.5 checkbox to switch blade layout with Ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-controller

I'm trying to have my laravel blade to switch layouts when a checkbox is selected/unselected, no visible result so far, What I am missing? Here's the relevant part of my code.

Blade `index.blade.php`

```
...    
@if ($tab == true)
<div style="background-color:green;height:100px;width:200px;">
    //for test porposes a div with diff color only
    some text
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="layout" value="1" onclick="processForm()" checked>
@else
<div style="background-color:red;height:100px;width:200px;">
    some text
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="layout" value="1" onclick="processForm()">
@endif

...

@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
function processForm() { 
   $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'articles/layout',
        data: { layout : $('input:checkbox:checked').val()},

        success: function(data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    } );
}
</script>
@stop
```

Routes

```
Route::resource('articles','ArticleController');
Route::post('articles/layout', [
        'as' => 'articles.layout',
        'uses' => 'ArticleController@layout'
    ]);
```

Finally controller `ArticleController.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Vanguard\Article;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::latest()->paginate(10);
        $page_title = "hello world";
        $page_title_sml = "small hello world";
        if (!isset($tab)) {
            $tab = false;
        }

        return view('articles.index',compact('articles', 'page_title' , 'page_title_sml', 'tab'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);

    }

...

 //custom function
        public function layout(Request $request)
    {
        $tab = $request->layout;
        return redirect()->route('articles.index')
                        ->with('success','Layout changed');
    }
    //end custom function
}
```

My logic is: Ajax monitor checkbox > once it's checked/unchecked, Ajax send post request to articles/layout > which trigger ArticleController@layout > which process checkbox variable > redirects to Controller's articles.index > to display blade accordingly.

What I'm missing? Is there a better/simpler way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: you don't need to redirect if you are using ajax just instead you can try `return Response()->json(['success'=>'Layout changes'])` please make sure response facades are already loaded

Comment: @PrateikDarji so I have  
`public function layout(Request $request)
    {
     $tab = $request->layout;
return Response()->json(['success'=>'Layout changes']);
}`

Still nothing